# How can I append all the columns of a matrix into one?

Tags: r

I would like to append all the columns of my matrix into one single column.

**Mock example**

```
# Sample data
testmat <- matrix (data = seq(1:3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

> testmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
```

I am expecting

```
     [,1]
[1,]    1 
[2,]    2 
[3,]    3
[4,]    1
[5,]    2
[6,]    3
[7,]    1
[8,]    2
[9,]    3
```

My first guess was something like:

```
onecol <- as.matrix (apply (X = testmat, MARGIN = 2, FUN = cat))
```

But it is not returning anything useful.

Any help?

Comment: Ho, that's much easier than I thaught! Thanks.

Comment: you could do `c(matrix)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need to use to `apply` here.  A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes, so if we call the `matrix` again on the original `matrix` and specify the `ncol` then it will change it to a `matrix` with 1 column

```
matrix(testmat, ncol=1)
```

---

or we can change the `dim` of the original `matrix` ('testmat')

```
dim(testmat) <- c(9, 1)
```

Comment: I think even just `matrix(testmat)` will work fine as well.